# Formula to sum certain color values only

Tags: excel, excel-formula, colors

In Excel, what's the formula that adds all cells in a column of certain colors only?

Comment: With the `+` sign? For example, if the desired cells are a1, a3 and a10, then do `=a1+a3+a10`.

Comment: You can't with a formula, so instead what makes the colors different?  Is it set by conditional formatting? Then, use what makes the colors change what you use in the formula to get the correct cells.

Comment: You will need a UDF to accomplish this because all Excel formulas are "blind" to cell colors.

Comment: Does this solve it?  https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/12/count-sort-by-color-excel/

Answer (score 0):

You should use a UDF as stated by Ralph.
This is how to use it and its code:
Open you worksheet
Press ALT + F11 to open the VBA Editor and navigate to Insert > Module.
Paste the "SumByColor" function in the Editor:

> ```
> Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, rRange As Range)
> Dim cSum As Long
> Dim ColIndex As Integer
> ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
> For Each c1 in rRange
> If c1.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex Then
> cSum = WorksheetFunction.SUM(c1, cSum)
> End If
> Next c1
> SumByColor = cSum
> End Function
> ```

Now you type in a cell SumByColor function this way =SumByColor(cell_with_background_color_that_you_wish_sum, Range_to_be_summed_up)

Answer (score 0):

There is no formula to get you the color of a cell, but you can indeed extract the color of a cell, two ways.

---

First, with a couple of user defined functions

```
Function BackgroundColor(MyCell As Range)
  BackgroundColor = MyCell.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function

Function TextColor(MyCell As Range)
  TextColor = MyCell.Font.Color
End Function
```

and using them this way

```
=TEXTCOLOR(A1)
=BACKGROUNDCOLOR(A1)
```

---

Second, with the old and deprecated `get.cell` function which unfortunately cannot be called directly, but thru a named range.

So, create a named range, call it TEXTCOLOR and set its value to refer to 
`GET.CELL(43,INDIRECT("rc",FALSE))`

so now, you just copy the complete column (so you take the color with you) and replace the content of every cell with a reference to this named range `=TEXTCOLOR`.

---

once you have all colors extracted as numbers you can then use them in your `countif` or `sumif` formulas.